# use variable in different functions in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, variables, global-variables, jsonp

I have this jQuery part and i want to use the var lString from my first function in my function (response). I have tried some return things but none didn't work.

```
$(".noar").live("click",function() {
var leString = $(this).attr("searchkey");
$.ajax({
    url: rootDomain + "kunden/intent24/js/pz.json?callback=jsonp"+leString,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "jsonp"+leString,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    success: function(size) { 
        jsonpParty(size);
        $("#lisize").show();
        $("#size").menuFlip();
    }
});
});

function jsonpParty(response){

var i,c = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer"><span>Choose size</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">', opt = $('<li/>');

var menu = response.size;
alert(leString);


for (i=0; i < menu.length; i++){
    c += '<li><span class="pointer search_link guddi" searchkey="xdz'+leString+' xdz'+ menu[i].measure +'" id="'+[i]+'">' + menu[i].measure + '</span></li>';
}

$('#size').html(c+'</ul>');     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another way to do it :

```
$(".noar").on("click",function() {
var leString = $(this).attr("searchkey");
$.ajax({
    url: rootDomain + "kunden/intent24/js/pz.json?callback=jsonp"+leString,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: "jsonp"+leString,
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    success: function(size) { 
        jsonpParty(size,leString);
        $("#lisize").show();
        $("#size").menuFlip();
    }
});
});

function jsonpParty(response,leString){

var i,c = '<div class="fn_menu_title pointer"><span>Choose size</span></div><ul class="fn_menu">', opt = $('<li/>');

var menu = response.size;
alert(leString);


for (i=0; i < menu.length; i++){
    c += '<li><span class="pointer search_link guddi" searchkey="xdz'+leString+' xdz'+ menu[i].measure +'" id="'+[i]+'">' + menu[i].measure + '</span></li>';
}

$('#size').html(c+'</ul>');     
}
```

P.S. Dont use `live()`, it's deprecated. Use `on()` instead

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `leString` variable inside other function , you need to define taht variable as `global variable` outside of function.

```
var leString = "";
```

Comment: I did define that but my alert(leString) in the function jsonParty is blank.

Comment: @SebastianRush you have to define it only once, outside the function, and then only give it a value: leString = $(this).attr("searchkey"); (without var)

Comment: remove var from this line var leString = $(this).attr("searchkey"); and the reason is we already declared leString as global outside of function so no need to define as var inside function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that variable outside of your live()-function.

```
var leString;
$(".noar").live("click",function() { 
leString = $(this).attr("searchkey"); ... });
```

Also the jquery .live() method is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9 ! You should replace it with:

```
$(document).on('click','.noar',function(){...});
```